# Can parameterized queries have output parameters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, parameterized-query

In SQL Server is there a way to have an output parameter return the total number of records (for paging) in a parameterized query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A stored procedure can have an output parameter, but not a standard query.  You could execute an initial query to get the record count, or return mutliple results sets from one query.

Answer (score 0):

No, but You can do something like that:

`SELECT 

  **,

  COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY ID) 

FROM TABLE`

Not very pretty, but returns record count. You can also use ROW_NUMBER().